# Помогите разобраться с url а точнее после url

Tags: url

Столкнулся с проблемкой, не знаю как сообразить, есть сайт на котором есть файлы товара, комментариев, обзора и тд. В кажды из файл передается гет запрос с юрл и при переключении между файлами остается тот-же юрлЮ а нужно переделать:

```
товар site.ru/product/url
комментарии site.ru/comment/url
фото и 3д  site.ru/photo/url
```

и тд
где  url - это адрес товара

```
Нужно сделать :
site.ru/url
site.ru/url/photo
site.ru/url/comment
site.ru/url/photo

работает это всё так:
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /ukr/product.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /ukr/comment.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)$ /ukr/photo.php?url=$1 [L]
```

передается if($_GET['product']){$product= $_GET['product'];

Задача такая примерно как на розетке, попереключайтесь между комментариями и тд.
http://rozetka.com.ua/samsung_galaxy_j7_ds_black/p3818722/

Comment: Ну так а если `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/photo$ /ukr/photo.php?url=$1 [L]` ?

Comment: Огромное спасибо (: